# status Online it's not displaying?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, socket.io

i have building a ionic chat app , using socket io for the backend , when i want to display the status online for the bakcend the console log of usersonline i can get the list of the user, but in the client side sometimes i get the list and others no?any help please i m newer for using this ?thanks
this the two back function for the events online and istyping
module.exports= function(io){
io.on('connection',(socket)=>{

```
    socket.on('join chat',params =>{
     //console.log(params)
       socket.join(params.room1)
       socket.join(params.room2)
    })
    socket.on('start_typing',data =>{
        io.to(data.receiver).emit('is_typing',data)
     })
     socket.on('stop_typing',(data)=>{
        io.to(data.receiver).emit('has_stop_typing',data)
     })
  })

  module.exports =  function(io, User, _){
  const users = new User()
  io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
    socket.on('refresh',(data)=>{
       io.emit('refreshPage',{})
    })
    socket.on('online',(data)=>{
        //console.log(data)
    socket.join(data.room)
    users.EnterRoom(socket.id,data.user,data.room)
    const list = users.GetList(data.room)
    //console.log(list)
    io.emit('usersOnline', _.uniq(list))
    })
    socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
        const user = users.RemoveUser(socket.id)
        if(user){
            const obj = users.GetList(user.room)
            const arr = _.uniq(obj)
            _.remove(arr, n=> n === user.name)
            io.emit('usersOnline', arr)
        }
        })
  })
 } 
 for the client side i have make this   IsTyping(){
 this.socket.emit('start_typing',{
  sender: this.username,
  receiver: this.receiverName
 })
 if(this.typingMessage){
  clearTimeout(this.typingMessage)
  }
 this.typingMessage= setTimeout(()=>{
  this.socket.emit('stop_typing',{
  sender: this.username,
  receiver: this.receiverName
})
},500)
}

 listening(){
this.socket.on('is_typing', (data:any) =>{
//console.log(data)
if ( data.sender === this.receiverName){
this.typing= true
}
  })
  this.socket.on('has_stop_typing',(data:any)=>{
if( data.sender === this.receiverName){
this.typing= false
}
  })

  this.socket.on('usersOnline',(data:any)=>{
    const result = _.indexOf(data,this.receiverName)
    //console.log(data)
    console.log(result)
     if(result > -1){
    this.isOnline= true

     }else{
       this.isOnline= false
    }
  })
}
ngOnInit() {
this.tokenservice.getPayload().then(value=>{
  this.user=value._id
  //console.log(this.user)
  this.getuser()
  this.getallmessage(this.user,this.receiverdata._id)
  //this.updateScroll();


  const val = {
    room:'global',
    user:this.username
  }
  this.socket.emit('online',val)

  const params= {
    room1:this.username,
    room2: this.receiverName
  }
  this.socket.emit('join chat',params)
})
this.socket.on('refreshPage', (data:any)=>{

  this.tokenservice.getPayload().then(value=>{
    this.user=value._id
    //console.log(this.user)
    this.getuser()
    this.getallmessage(this.user,this.receiverdata._id)
    this.updateScroll();

  })
  this.listening()
  })

}
ionViewDidEnter(){
const params= {
room1:this.username,
room2: this.receiverName
}
this.socket.emit('join chat',params)
```

}